# Xcode - iPhone cannot be used to deploy my app (Developer Mode disabled)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

After upgrading to **Xcode 14**, and update my iPhone to **iOS 16**, my iPhone is no more eligible to deploy application from Xcode.

*(Developer Mode disabled)*

[image]

**Which manipulation should I make to enable developer mode ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you move your mouse over the message (Developer Mode disabled), Xcode will display a hint indicating what you have to do to enable developer mode.

In your iPhone : **Settings > Privacy & Security > Developer Mode**

[image]

Comment: Or just read the docs. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device

Answer (score 0):

You should active your developer mode in your iPhone. Settings -> Privacy & Security after scroll to end of this page(Privacy & Security) -> Developer Mode (Switch on). When you switch developer mode, your phone will restart. After you can use.